# Qt threads for an desktop interface

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, printing

I am developing a Qt interface for a 3D printer. When I cilck the Print button (the printer starts printing) the interface crashes. I am using this code:

```
*future= QtConcurrent::run(Imprimir,filename.toUtf8().data());
```

What can I use to solve it?? What types of threads can I use????

I need to use the interface while the printer is printing (it may take several minutes).

Thank you for advance.

**Edit:**

`Imprimir` function:

```
int Imprimir(char *fich)
{
    char *aux = new char;
    FILE *f;

    f=fopen(fich, "r");

     while(!feof(f)){
        fgets(aux, 200, f);
        Enviar(aux);
        while(!seguir_imprimiendo);
     }

     Sleep(7000);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show the contents of the `Imprimir` function/functor. That function should probably be streaming data to the printer in the background, allowing it to be used from any thread, but instead it blocks.

Comment: The function `Imprimir` sends to the printer gcode instructions with `Enviar` function.

Comment: @KubaOber was on the right track. The problem IS in your `Imprimir` function. You're allocating room for one char in `aux` and reading 200 chars into it. Change to `char *aux = new char[200]`. Also, my answer below may still apply.

Answer (score 2):

It's making life harder than necessary by not using `QFile`. When you use `QFile`, you don't have to deal with silly things like passing C-string filenames around. You're likely to do it wrong, since who's to guarantee that the platform expects them to be encoded in `UTF-8`. The whole point of Qt is that it helps you avoid such issues. They are taken care of, the code is tested on multiple platforms to ensure that the behavior is correct in each case.

By not using `QByteArray` and `QFile`, you're liable to commit silly mistakes like your C-classic bug of allocating a single character buffer and then pretending that it's 200 characters long.

I see no reason to sleep in that method. It also makes no sense to wait for the continue flag `seguir_imprimiendo` to change, since `Enviar` runs in the same thread. It should block until the data is sent.

I presume that you've made `Enviar` run its code through `QtConcurrent::run`, too. This is unnecessary and leads to a deadlock. Think of what happens if a free thread can never be available while `Imprimir` is running. It's valid for the pool `Imprimir` runs on to be limited to just one thread. You can't simply pretend that it can't happen.

```
bool Imprimir(const QString & fileName)
{
  QFile src(fileName);
  if (! src.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) return false;
  QByteArray chunk;
  do {
    chunk.resize(4096);
    qint64 read = src.read(chunk.data(), chunk.size());
    if (read < 0) return false;
    if (read == 0) break; //we're done
    chunk.resize(read);
    if (!Enviar(chunk)) return false;
  } while (! src.atEnd());
  return true;
}

bool Enviar(const QByteArray & data)
{
  ...
  return true; // if successful
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try it on Monday. I haven't experience in Qt and I'm very lost with the threads.

Comment: The threading is a general concept, not having much to do with Qt at all. It is somewhat of a conceptual obstacle, I admit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's no problem with `Imprimir`, the issue is probably with `filename.toUtf8().data()`. The data pointer you get from this function is only valid while `filename` is in-scope. When `filename` goes out of scope, the data may be deleted and any code accessing the data will crash.

You should change the `Imprimir` function to accept a `QString` parameter instead of `char*` to be safe.

If you can't change the `Imprimir` function (because it's in another library, for example), then you will have to wrap it in your own function which accepts a QString. If you're using C++11, you can use a lambda expression to do the job:

```
QtConcurrent::run([](QString filename) {
    Imprimir(filename.toUtf8().data());
}, filename);
```

If not, you will have to write a separate `ImprimirWrapper(QString filename)` function and invoke it using `QtConcurrent::run`.

Comment: I can't change the `char*` because `Imprimir` is a C function in a library out of QT.

Comment: I actually had a feeling this would be the case. I amended my answer to account for that.

Comment: @kova Then you better figure out what exact encoding of the filename does that function expect.